# Teensy 2.0 MIDI: Number of notes in a chord limited to 6?

Tags: usb, library, teensy, midi

I am using the Teensy 2.0 with USBMidi in a project that allows musicians to use retro computers as "instruments" (https://github.com/fredlcore/midijoy). So far, all these computers had no more than four voices, so the problem I am encoutering now has not arisen so far.

When I now want to play a chord with more than six notes simultaneously, only the first six notes are received and played. However, if I release two from, let's say, eight notes, the remaining two notes are subsequently being played if these keys are still kept pressed.

Here is a script reduced to the bare minimum, when you press eight keys on the MIDI device one after another, you'll see that it stops after the sixth key, and when you then subsequently keep all keys pressed and release one after the other, you'll see that the "remaining" keys/notes will be received then:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  usbMIDI.setHandleNoteOn(doNote); 
  usbMIDI.setHandleNoteOff(doNoteOff); 
}

void loop() {
  usbMIDI.read(); 
}

void doNote(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  Serial.println(channel);
  Serial.println(pitch);
}

void doNoteOff(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  Serial.println(channel);
  Serial.println(pitch);
}
```

You have to configure the Teensy as a MIDI device so that the USBMidi libraries will be found.

Is there a hardware limit in the Teensy 2.0 that will prevent it from processing more than six notes at a time? Or is this a constraint within the library?

Comment: MIDI has no concept of chords. It's more likely whatever it is you're using to send the MIDI messages that can't cope with more than 6 note polyphony.

Comment: Connect the keyboard to a PC and run a MIDI monitor. I guess that you will see the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Majenko pointed me to the root cause of the problem: I was sending MIDI notes via Ableton's feature of using the computer's keyboard. It seems that the OS (or the keyboard) cannot send/receive more than six simultaneous keystrokes.

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem. You may have to wait for 48 hours before you can accept it.

Comment: That's a feature of USB keyboards. They have "N-key rollover" where N=6. I.e., the HID report has space for 6 keys in it.

Comment: @Majenko: Yes, that makes sense. Do you want to write up an answer yourself so I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: No, yours is good enough. Accept your own when the system lets you.

Comment: Ok, will do....